# Binding a Property of an object in Item (row) to a DataGridCell Property in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, styles, multibinding

Using Release WPF `DataGrid` I am trying to bind to the property of a `CellViewModel` (that supports `INotifyPropertyChanged` of course). I am binding the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection` of type `RowViewModel` (which is inherited from Dr.WPF's `ObservableDictonary`) of type `CellViewModel` and I want bind to a property of a `CellViewModel`.

For example in what follows I am trying to change the state of the `DatagridCell.FontStyle` property based on my `CellViewModel.IsLocked` boolean property (so that if `IsLocked` then Italic).

First to get expose the relevant CellViewModelobject in XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

       <cv:RowColumnToCellConverter x:Key="RowColumnToCellConverter"/>

        <MultiBinding x:Key="CellViewModel" Converter="{StaticResource RowColumnToCellConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="Column" />
        </MultiBinding>

</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The RowColumnToCellConverter is

```
public class RowColumnToCellConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
        RowViewModel<string,CellViewModel> row = values[0] as RowViewModel<string,CellViewModel>;
        string column = (values[1] as DataGridColumn).SortMemberPath;
        string col = column.Substring(1, column.Length - 2);
        return row[col];
   }
   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
 }
```

Then create the `DataTrigger` in XAML:

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True" >
                    <DataTrigger.Binding >
                          <Binding Path="isLocked" Source="{StaticResource CellViewModel}" />
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>             
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Now this does not work but is an example of what I would *like* to do, hopefully it is not far off. Certainly the `MultiBinding` is never set here (since the `Converter` is never called checking in debug).

Elsewhere the `MultiBinding/MultiConverter` works (although I cut it down for this post hopefully did not introduce any errors) that is as a part of a `DataTrigger/MultiTrigger` (not as a StaticResource as in the above - which is what I would *like*)) but then it only reveals an object that is not iself bound to.

That is I could have a variant of converter where the object returned is *row[col].Islocked* however then the Islocked Property is not registered for PropertyChange notifications.

Now I cannot add the `IsLocked` property (or can I?) as a third bind statement for the BindingCollection in the original MultiBind, as until the MultiBind returns an object, there is nothing for the third bind statement *{Bind Path=IsLocked}* to refer to.

So I tried nesting `MultiBinding` in something like the following which does not work since `BindingCollection` only accepts Binding objects not `MultBinding` objects.

```
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger>
                     <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowColumnToCellConverter}">
                                <Binding />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="Column" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                            <Binding Path="IsLocked"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>              
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Hopefully my problem should be clear from the above even if my attempted solutions are far off. So what am I missing? (Probably a lot since I have only been using WPF/MVVM for a few weeks and this is a really basic requirement for working with any DataGrid, so I hope the answer is embarrassingly simple).